# What do Jews do on Sunday? Do they pray as on weekdays?

Tags: tefilla, chol-weekday

I was just wanting to know does Sunday have 3 prayers like weekdays?

Comment: Why should it not be?

Comment: In Israel Sunday is the equivalent of Monday in Europe and America

Comment: There is sometimes one practical difference (outside Israel): many shuls change the schedules on Sunday because people may find a different time to be more convenient when they're not going to work.  But the content is the same as any other weekday.

Comment: If you're asking because Christians celebrate Sundays as their Sabbath, that would be our Saturday, which indeed has four prayers and not three.

Comment: A bit of clarification, perhaps. In Judaism, the calendar day begins at sundown while in many other religions it begins at midnight, which is a fixed time. So, our "Sunday" almost always begins before Christianity's (and most other religions') Sunday. Regardless, as explained, below, in most cases, there are still 3 prayers, but the first one of "Sunday" is actually the evening prayer, not the morning one.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. In Judaism, Sunday is a weekday just like any other.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that nothing else such as New Moon, a "major holiday" (where most work is forbidden) or the intermediary days of Passover or Tabernacles (Succot) coincides. Otherwise,  there are, technically 4 if you include Musaph (additional "service") as an extra "prayer".